# How do I wrap lines in a column in a table

Tags: tables

I am making a table in a two-column document and one of the table columns is running out of the page. This is a sample of the table. I would like to wrap the last column in the table. How can I solve this?

```
\begin{table}[b]

\caption{}
\label{snps.tab}%
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
SNP & Chromosome & Gene & LOD score & Annotation \\
\colrule
rs33321100 & chr17 & Srd5a2 & 3.79 & 3-oxo-5-alpha-steroid 4-dehydrogenase 2 \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}%
\end{table}
```

Comment: you might want to check out the `array` package, which provides a column format `p` which is "paragraph" format and the text will wrap.

Comment: @FionaSmith `p` is standard latex it doesn't need any package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks! I always put in `array` because I wanted its other features and it mentions it in the doc so I thought it must be 'special'

Comment: Since your table appears to be far too wide to fit in a single column of a two-column document, you may want to use the `table*` environment instead of the `table` environment. Note, though, that `table*` (and `figure*`) environments can only be placed at the top of a page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Using a `p` column type since of the basic `l` column type may be of lower urgency to the OP. Though not mentioned explicitly by the OP, he/she faces a second, much greater problem: The `tabular` material is simply too wide to fit in a single column. The OP will have to use a `table*` environment.

Comment: I tried `p` and it results in an error for me. The document doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: You probably have a missing parameter - Did you try p{width}? e.g. p{3cm}

Comment: `  \begin{tabular}{ l l l l p{3.5cm} }` you might need to put an `mbox{}` to force a line break in a good place.

Comment: Okay, I decided to give up on trying to fit it in a single column and used table*. However, the toprule and bottom rule only extend to the first column and not the second. The text extends fine. What is to be done about them?